# phpass: why would HashPassword fail?

Tags: php, phpass

I'm reading [phpass manual](http://www.openwall.com/articles/PHP-Users-Passwords). At some point, it checks the result of the hashing like this:

```
$hash = $hasher->HashPassword($pass);
if (strlen($hash) < 20)
    fail('Failed to hash new password');
```

I understand that's the minimum lenght for a phpass hash, but I don't understand why would it fail. Is it even possible? I mean, who/what should I blame if it happens? How to prevent that? I also posted a comment about this in the web page.

*For reference, you can find the code of `PasswordHash::HashPassword()` in this question: [How can * be a safe hashed password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596375/how-can-be-a-safe-hashed-password)*

Comment: A suggestion: The PHP developers are currently working on PHP 5.5. This will include dedicated functions for working with secure passwords. (See here: http://www.h-online.com/security/news/item/PHP-5-5-should-reduce-password-sloppiness-1707835.html). However, a version of this library is available to use in older PHP versions already. You can download it from here: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat . It might be worth considering using it, since it will very shortly be the PHP standard.

Comment: have you included the phpass class?

Comment: @rsz: well, actually I haven't started using it. I just wondered what should I tell the user when `HashPassword()` fails... like "no strange characters", and how to prevent such situations. @Spudley: I'm on php 5.2 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that some underlying libraries, such as 'crypt' don't fail gracefully when something is wrong, but just return a shorter string.

Maybe this is a symptom of this problem, and just an extra precaution.

Comment: This headed me to look for "fail" in [crypt() docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) and get the answer I wanted. Problems would be invalid characters in salt, or other invalid parameters. So it really seems just an extra precaution.